# How to find the 'average' of a word

Tags: computational-linguistics

I am trying to extract words that are similar between several documents. I would then like to extract the 'average' of the similar words

**Input**

```
Document 1               Document 2             Document 3       
now                      news                    now
elephantine              wheelbarrow            grass
great                    greet                  groat
inow                     newsy                  now
```

**Desired result**

```
nows

great
```

I have done this so far by using Levenshtein distance to extract words that are sufficiently similar but what process can I use to get the average result (note that I have assumed that this is the average result but happy to accept any result given a method to calculate an average).

I would just ascribe an index to each letter and then average that index with the aligned letter in the next word but occasionally the letters do not align eg.

```
inow
newsy
```

Is there another established way preferably using java- but any solution with the terminology to look up for this kind of problem will do

Comment: Why is 'nows' better than 'new'?

Comment: I don't think the idea of an "average" word is well defined enough. And I don't think this really has anything to do with linguistics.

Comment: This is a valid question in computational linguistics, which is how he tagged it. If you don't understand the question, please don't suspend his question due to your own lack of knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are pretty close to the expected result. The remaining steps left to make are:

1. build a weighed graph containing all words of a group (the edge weight is the Levenshtein distance); and
2. find the word having **minimal sum of edge weights**.

This will, obviously, only include **words that exist** in the original corpus.
If you, however, need your code to "invent" non-existing words, you would need to generate a whole (huge) list of possible transmutations and see if any newly-invented transmute word, being *infused* to the graph, has a smaller sum of edge weights than any of the existing ones.

It also seems to be possible to **reduce the list of transmutations**. Levenshtein distance, by definition, is the number of atomic permutations, and each mutation stand for a newly-invented word. So, one can remember these permutations while computing the original Levenshtein distance between each pair of words and subsequently use it as a list of candidates.